# Connect TYPO3 to MySQL using SSL

Tags: mysql, typo3

Is it possible to connect TYPO3 CMS to MySQL over SSL? I found this feature request from 7 years ago but seems like the feature was never implemented.

Support secure database connections (e.g. MySQL over SSL)
http://forge.typo3.org/issues/17108

Answer (score 2):

At the moment it is not possible with the standard core of TYPO3 to connect over SSL to another server.

There also not seems to be an extension in TER.

But it should be possible to create a custom extension. You have to

- extend `DatabaseConnection.php`
- override the `connectDB()` method
- create a config file for the ssl login data
- get them somehow in your extension
- let TYPO3 use extended class by creating a `ext_localconf.php` inside your extension folder with this content:

```php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects']['TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Database\\DatabaseConnection'] = array('className' => 'Vendorname\\YourExtensionName\\Database\\DatabaseConnection');
```

**Edit:** Updated the answer to fit to SSL

Comment: Stefano, you're mixing up SSL and SSH at some point, I would say. While the way described should be IMHO correct also for "just" doing SSL-encrypted DB connections, some steps you described are not needed (no extra variables needed, I would say).

Comment: Steffen, you are right. I totally overread that. I updated my answer to SSL.